# What is the correct European convention for annotating circuit diagrams?

Tags: circuit-analysis, european

I am compiling training material and would like to stick to the European symbols and convention in annotating circuit diagrams.

What is the correct way to mark currents and voltages?

I attach an example below showing possible annotations for the inductors.

[image: Circuitikz (European)]

Which annotation styles in this Circuitikz diagram is preferred or mandatory in Europe.  Can you provide a reference?

I also attach the Overleaf code for easy reference:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[european,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,2) to [short,i^=$i_1(t)$] (1,2) to [short] (4,2);
 \draw (0,0) to [short,f_=$i_2(t)$     ] (1,0) to [L, i_=$i_3(t)$, l_=$L_3$, v^<=$u_3(t)$](4,0);
 \draw (0,-2) to [short,f=$i_4(t)$     ] (1,-2) to [L, i^=$i_5(t)$, l=$L_5$, v<=$u_5(t)$](4,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a single agreed standard but you should be consistent.  I personally use a arrowhead on the wire to show currents so would prefer \$ i_1 \$,  \$ i_3 \$ and  \$ i_5 \$ to \$ i_2 \$ and \$ i_4 \$.  Your voltage notation looks fine.

Comment: You could start here: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm:978-1-349-04793-2/1.pdf

Comment: @SolarMike, thanks but I am still hoping for a more recent reference such as IEC 60050 at http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/index?openform&part=131 although that is not for circuit symbols and annotations.

Comment: What is "Europe"? And what makes you think that an EE in any given country in "Europe" is required to write currents and voltages in any specific way?

Comment: @EML, I was looking for an IEC standard.  It is known that the resistor (and other) symbols differ in European and American standards.